# What are the possible characters on an Xbox code

Tags: xbox-network

So, Xbox redeemable codes are 25 character case insensitive strings of letters and numbers.  However, it has been suggested that not all letter/number combinations might appear (eg. 0/O).  In the interest of fraud detection, what is the definitive (read as: {{Citation needed}}) list of possible characters which might make up this string?

Bonus points: given these additional rules, what are the number of possible strings that could be formed.

Comment: While gaming related, I don't think this is a gaming question.  Any 25-character string with the same restrictions will have the same possibilities.

Comment: @Matt the restrictions are sort of an aside (mostly to make the question more fun), it is the rules I am interested in.  Gaming.SE has long been established as a source for questions about consoles and their services ([cite](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-live)).

Comment: @Matt if you think this is a math question, please re-read it.

Comment: @tzenes The way you used "rules" and "restrictions" differently in your comment confused me.  They're not different :P If the question's "What are the restrictions/rules for forming an Xbox code?" then yeah, not a math question.

Comment: @Matt that should read "possibilities" not restrictions.  It was a reference to the second sentence of your first comment.

Comment: Why do you want to know? What real-world problem are you looking to solve? Right now this just reads as a meaningless trivia question.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Says it's in the interest of "fraud detection". Perhaps because of getting a questionable-looking code that doesn't seem quite right?

Comment: @Grace Note: Ah, nevermind—It's to resolve [a debate in the comments here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20229/xbox-redeem-codes-recycled/21994#21994).

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but I do have a partial one. I used a 1600 Point Xbox Live card last night. The code contained both 8 and B, something I didn't think it would due to possibly being able to confuse one for the other.

Comment: @Seven Hah, that exchange [just reminds me of a very similar question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771/is-a-guid-unique-100-of-the-time/39776#39776).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I went straight to the source and just e-mailed Xbox Support. I didn't think they would answer, but to my surprise, they did respond (screenshot of email is the best proof i can give) with the invalid characters.

There are 8 invalid letters and 3 invalid digits:

```
A E I O U L S N      0 1 5
```

That leaves them with 18 valid letters and 7 valid digits:

```
B C D F G H J K M P Q R T V W X Y Z     2 3 4 6 7 8 9
```

With 25 characters needed for a code and 25 possible letters and digits, if my math is right, and it's entirely possible it is not, that's (18+7)<sup>25</sup> which my calculator says is 8.8817842 × 10<sup>34</sup>, which equals a whole lot of different combinations.

Screenshot of the e-mail from Xbox Support:
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't that be (18+7)^25? I don't have my math-brain on right now, but by analogy to binary-number size calculations: an 8-bit binary number gives 2^8 possible permutations, which is digits^length. In this case we have (18+7) available digits, and a length of 25: (18+7)^25 or 25^25… which, oh hey, *in this specific case* it doesn't matter which way around they are. ;)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie You are right, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Wonder why they don't use S or N.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer S is too much like the 5 they don't include. But I can't figure out why the N

Comment: I would guess N because of M. B and 8 are both acceptable, and that surprises me a little.